# Redirecting page links after .htaccess SEO upgrade?

Tags: .htaccess, seo

I didn't want to bloat one post here with a ton of .htaccess questions, so I'm breaking them up individually. This one has to do with using `RedirectMatch` to create rules for existing, indexed pages that are part of an existing website.

Specifically, my test site has been up for about a year and I am now using .htaccess to re-write clean URLs for better SEO. So when I had a container page whose content was called based on a query string in a link, like so:

`http://www.website.com/departments.php?dep=contact_us`

I'm working on making the URL appear smoother like:

`http://www.website.com/contact-us/`

The tutorial I read suggested that changing my links to the new, snazzier SEO-friendly style would lead to lots of 404 errors and broken page links until the site has been indexed again and the records brought up to date.

Thus, my question: Is this a legitimate concern or will the new links be picked up in 24-48 hours?

I ask because I have several websites with many layers of file structure and I'm thinking that I'd need a TON  of rules in my .htaccess file to fix all the broken links I may be creating.

If I'm creating confusion here, please let me know and I'll clarify things.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Thus, my question: Is this a legitimate concern or will the new links be picked up in 24-48 hours?

You can make it happen sooner if you externally redirect the client using a 301 (permanent). This is a lot trickier than internally rewriting on the server's end because you'll cause conflicting rules. For example, if you wanted to rewrite url-a to url-b internally on the server, then redirect the browser from url-b to url-a (meaning when a client specifically requests url-b to redirect it to url-a):

```
# internally rewrite url-a (fake URL) to url-b (where the actual content is)
RewriteRule ^url-a$ /url-b [L]

# externally redirect url-b (actual content) to url-a (fake URL)
RewriteRule ^url-b$ /url-a [L,R=301]
```

Since the rewrite engine loops, these 2 rules will continue to rewrite each other and cause a 500 internal server error (the same thing happens if you replace the second rule with a `RedirectMatch`). To fix this, you need to create a condition so that the external redirect (second rule) only gets applied if the **actual request was for "url-b"**. You can do this by matching against the `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable, which is essentially the first line of an HTTP request.

Using your example URLs, you'd have something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^contact-us/?$ /departments.php?dep=contact_us [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /departments\.php\?dep=contact_us
RewriteRule ^ /contact-us/ [L,R=301]
```

This means when someone like a google-bot attempts to resolve `http://www.website.com/departments.php?dep=contact_us`, the 2nd rule's condition will match the request (which will look something like: `GET /departments.php?dep=contact_us HTTP/1.1`) and it will get redirected to `http://www.website.com/contact-us/`. At which point, the client (google-bot) will request `/contact-us/` and the first rule will get applied and internally rewrite the URI to `/departments.php?dep=contact_us`.

Comment: My friend, you are an amazing source of knowledge. The only downside I see to this is having to add a rule for each and every page. Two questions arise here: How long will it take for the new links to index? Secondly, there's an article here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/ about a third of the way down where cutom PHP functions are suggested. Would these be a more flexible workaround? Again, may hige thanks!

Comment: @mileaminute If there's a general pattern for mapping stuff like `/contact-us/` to `/departments.php?dep=contact_us` you can replace the `contact-us` part with regular expressions, like `([^/]+)` and backreference using `$1`. Using php to redirect is definitely a more flexible option. The php script (like in this instance, `departments.php`) would know that it was requested directly (as opposed to an internal redirect) and redirect to the appropriate URL when that happens.

Comment: So at the risk of appearing as though I'm still largely in over my head here, if this were your own project, would you do it with .htaccess or the PHP function?

Comment: Additionally, I'm still curious as to how long the new links will take to index. Is it the 24-48 hours we expect when changing DNS settings or is it longer. My thought is, if it's only 48 hours, why bother with the redirects at all?

Comment: @mileaminute If everything is being routed through one (or two) php scripts (like the way wordpress works), then it's much easier to do the redirect to the nicer looking URL in php, since it happens in one place. If there's dozens of scripts, it may be easier to do it in htaccess. If the SEO friendly URL scheme requires a database lookup, then it must happen in php. There's no "best" way, it entirely depends on your context.

Comment: @mileaminute It takes as long for a place like google to update their links to your site as it does for their indexing bot to get to an older link. This is different for every website, some highly trafficked sites get indexed a lot more frequently than low traffic sites. I don't know how long it will take for your links and I don't think there's a way for you to force google to re-index.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Here's my new .htaccess file as you suggested: `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/?Home/?$ /index.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^Contact-Us/?$ /about_us.php?about=contact_us [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /about_us\.php\?about=contact_us
RewriteRule ^/Contact-Us/ [L,R=301]`

Now what I'm trying to figure out is the Regex to allow any of the other query strings to be replaced. As you can see, I changed the departments page title to about_us and the query string variable to about.

Comment: You need to remember that a redirect may be required forever. It's easy to fix your internal links so they use the new URLs but you may find it very hard to fix all links from around the internet. While there are still old links you still want the redirects.